# Uploading multiple files using React and DRF returns success/200 but no objects created and no files saved

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

Trying to upload multiple files using React and DRF. I get a 200 response, but nothing actually gets saved to the database and no files are created. No issues if I remove the many=True from the serializer constructor and just upload a single file.

React Post Code:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData();
        for (let i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
            formData.append('file', uploadedFiles[i]);
        }
        axiosInstance.post("productmedia/", formData, {headers: {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}});
    };
```

Model

```
class ProductMedia(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='media', null=True, blank=True)
```

Serializer

```
class ProductMediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductMedia
        fields = ('file',)
```

View

```
class ProductMediaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductMediaSerializer
    queryset = ProductMedia.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = ProductMediaSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Check `request.data` or `request.FILES` within the `create(...)` method and see whats in the request.

Comment: It's a QueryDict. This is what it looks like if I print to console: <QueryDict: {'file': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: f1.png (image/png)>, <TemporaryUploadedFile: f2.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>

Comment: If I print request.FILES instead it is <MultiValueDict: {'file': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: f1.png (image/png)>, <TemporaryUploadedFile: f2.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>

Comment: I guess it's a misunderstanding on my part with respect to how the many=True behaves. I had to update my code to something like this: 

mylist = []
        for f in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
            mylist.append({'file': f})

        serializer = PieceMediaSerializer(data=mylist, many=True)

Answer (score 2):

You must inspect your request.data. For the bulk create, it should be in list form. You should check this for your reference https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-create

Also it would be better to override create in Serializer class itself.